# How to remove sub-directory name from filepath

Tags: python

`dirpath` variable points to a directory with two sub-folders both named 'Temp':

```
dirpath='C:/Users/Temp/AppData/Local/Temp'
```

Another variable `word` stores the name of directory that needs to removed from `dirpath`
but only if it is a last sub-folder:

```
word='temp'
```

So the final result should be:

```
result='C:/Users/Temp/AppData/Local'
```

Please note the "Temp" in `dirpath` starts with uppercase. While the `word` variable defines 'temp' in lower case. The final result should preserve original upper case characters used in `dirpath` variable .

How to achieve this with a minimum code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to work with the ["os" module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html).

In particular to the following two functions:

os.path.join() and os.path.split()

If you use os.path.split() then you can use os.path join to get the final path when you remove the last component of the list.  In your case the first split would give you what you want.

```
>>> import os
>>> dirpath='C:/Users/Temp/AppData/Local/Temp'
>>> dirpath
'C:/Users/Temp/AppData/Local/Temp'
>>> os.path.split(dirpath)
('C:/Users/Temp/AppData/Local', 'Temp')
>>> result = os.path.split(dirpath)
>>> result[0]
'C:/Users/Temp/AppData/Local'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the regular expression module `re`

```
import re
dirpath = 'C:/Users/Temp/AppData/Local/Temp'
word = 'temp'

if re.search("/%s$"%word, dirpath.lower()):
    dirpath = dirpath[:-len(word)] 

print dirpath
```

Maybe you combine this with the first answer, I'm not that good with the `os`-module

Comment: There are methods provided by `os.path` that handle exactly this. There is no need for regular expressions.

Comment: You are right, but I admitted my lack of knowledge about `os`-methods in my last sentence and pointed the user to the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
dirpath='C:/Users/Temp/AppData/Local/Temp'
word='temp'

if dirpath.lower().endswith(word.lower()):
    dirpath=dirpath[:-(len(word)+1)]
```

Comment: There are methods provided by `os.path` that handle exactly this.